# batch cmd parsing and rewriting an ini file

Tags: parsing, batch-file, cmd, ini

I'm trying to make changes to an existing ini file and then rewrite those changes to a new ini file. The problem I am having is parsing the sections doesn't seem to work. If I use the following code:

```
set reso=%2
set RESLINE=RESMAX=0.72
set nRESLINE=RESMAX=%reso%

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('findstr "^" %INIFILE%') do (
    set "lines=%%a"
    if defined lines set "lines=!lines:%p4p%=%new%!"
    if defined lines set "lines=!lines:%RESLINE%=%nRESLINE%!"
    echo(!lines!
)
) > new.ini
```

I get out a new.ini file which when the %p4p% variable is found in line, it replaces it with %new% which is fine. 
But when the RESLINE hits my output shows:

```
0.72=RESMAX=0.70=0.72
```

instead of:

```
RESMAX=0.70
```

as desired. I suspect this is because of the "=" being present in the strings, but I'm not sure how to get around it.

What I've tried doing instead is the following:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('findstr "^" %INIFILE%') do (
    set "lines=%%a"
    if defined lines set "lines=!lines:%p4p%=%new%!"

    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%y in ('%lines%') do (
    if %%y==RESMAX (
        set "oRES=%%z"
        set "lines=!lines:%oRES%=%reso%!"
    )
    )
    echo(!lines!
)
) > test.ini
```

But it seems in this case that the nested for doesn't ever read in the right information. 
I assumed what I was attempting here was to parse the read in line which should be of the format PARAM=VALUE, then check if the PARAM is = the word RESMAX and if it is, assign its corresponding value to the var oRES and then set the read-in line to now say RESMAX=newvalue. I've tried replacing the %lines% with !lines! but that just gets me a series of errors saying the various ini params don't exist as acceptable programs/batchs.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you're right - it's not so easy to replace `=` with batch  - check this http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1485&start=30

Comment: It can be done differently if the line in the INI file is precisely `RESMAX=nnnn` where nnnn is to be changed.  It can even be done if the line is not precisely that, but we need to know what format the line really is, or the exact transformation that is being done on the entire INI file.  There's usually more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: The RESMAX line format is RESMAX=n.nnn ;however, only the first digit is mandatory, the remaining may or may not be there. The starting nnnn is not always the same number, it can be variable from system to system.  The whole INI file is mostly being copied line for line, there are only two or three instances which get changed based on user-input when the batch runs. This one is the only instance I haven't been able to sort out. The others all fall into categories of either being a path where i'm changing just filename or there are defined number of char at the end of the line I can strip off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set "reso=%2"
set "old_reso=0.72"
set "RESLINE=RESMAX=0.72"
set "nRESLINE=RESMAX=%reso%"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
    for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('findstr "^" %INIFILE%') do (
        set "lines=%%a"
        if defined lines set "lines=!lines:%p4p%=%new%!"
        if defined lines ( 
          rem set "lines=!lines:%RESLINE%=%nRESLINE%!"
          echo !lines! | find /i "%RESLINE%" >nul 2>&1 && (
            set "lines=!lines:%old_reso%=%reso%!"
          )
         )
        (echo(!lines!)
    )

) > new.ini
```

Try this. Or check dbenham's [REPLVAR](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5492)  (the problem is that you cant directly replace the `=` sign)

Comment: This seems to have worked. I'll have to test it for a variety of values. What is the find statement actually doing? What I've done is set old_reso to %RESLINE:~7% to strip off the "RESMAX=" and leave whatever is left. Will that cause me any issues? THANKS.

Comment: If everything is ok you can accept the answer :-) . Find command cheks if certain string is presented in piped input - chekck in ss64.com for more info. Your new approach should not cause a problem as as the striped old_res does not contain , : ~ or equal sign